# Key of Map is Serializable, though returns error

Tags: java, dictionary, serializable

**Class with `Maps`**

```
public class Page {
    private Map<LocaleWrapper, String> titles;
    private Map<LocaleWrapper, String> texts;

    (...)
}
```

**Key class**

```
public class LocaleWrapper implements Serializable {
    private Locale locale;

    //Constructor, getter, setter
}
```

My IDE throws an error:

`Basic attributes can only be of the following types: (...), or any Serializable type.`

Why does my IDE throw this error and how can I fix my mappings?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post complete error please. And also specify what you are trying to do?

Comment: This is not in runtime yet, all I'm trying to do is to map titles and texts of different Locales. This way I can display the right title and text, depending on the Locale of the user.

Comment: So, at least tell where your IDE is giving you that error? And what is the exact error message. Without more information it's difficult to tell what went wrong.

Comment: I am using Netbeans 7.2.1, in my classfile there's an error pop-up. I've uploaded an image to clarify it: http://img502.imageshack.us/img502/8948/errorlv.png

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html It actually is, I have tried this wrapper because more people seem to have this problem according to Google, one of them said he fixed it by using a Serializable wrapper. But that shouldn't make any difference as they are both Serializable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error, AFAIK, is displayed because the attribute is inside a JPA entity, and not just a simple class.

And Map is not serializable.

Do you really want to save the whole map as a serialized byte array, in a BLOB column? If so, choose a serializable type, like HashMap. If not, then the map needs to define some form of association between entities and/or embedded types, and I would first think about how you want to store the information in the database, and map the database schema to entities.

Comment: You're right. I am using a JPA entity but would not have thought this was causing it. Does this mean I cannot handle any Maps inside a Entity? Should I use a custom class for this?

Comment: Thank you for you're answer. `Do you really want to save the whole map`,  are you suggesting I'd better not save an entire map? If so, is there a better solution for saving multiple titles and texts depending on the right `Locale`? Note. I'm trying to avoid using Properties, as the text might get edited through my CMS.

Comment: The question is *Do you really want to save the whole map as a serialized byte array, in a BLOB column?*. This is of course doable, but changing the implementation of any of the values in the map will lead to unreadable blobs, and you will of course be unable to execute any database query against the values in the map. Using JPA is not an excuse for not doing any database design.

Comment: Ok, I will consider the options. Thanks for your outstanding help!